# how to echo Json data in foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, json

Hello every one i am working on wego flight api after sending post request i have an array of json data in following pattern

```
{"response":{
"pendingResults":"true",
"itineraries":[
{"ecpcRank":0,"inboundInfo":{"aircraftTypes":[],"departureTime":1401116400000,"layoverInMin":0,"flightNumbers":["SQ981"],"durationInMin":85,"airportsExpanded":["BKK","SIN"],"localDepartureTimeStr":"2014/05/26 22:00 +0700","airports":["BKK","SIN"],"arrivalTime":1401121500000,"numStops":0,"flightClasses":[{"name":"Economy","fareClass":1}],"localArrivalTimeStr":"2014/05/27 00:25 +0800"},"location":[{"code":"BKK","name":"Bangkok"},{"code":"SIN","name":"Singapore Changi"}],"carrier":[{"name":"Singapore Airlines","code":"SQ"}],"bookingType":"WEBSITE","price":{"name":"","nameOTA":"","description":"","amount":"406","totalAmount":"406","pricePerPassenger":"406","currencyCode":"USD","totalPricePerPassenger":"406","includesTax":true},"generatedDate":1399013553817,"providerId":"singaporeair.com","id":"SQ974[SIN-BKK]|SQ981[BKK-SIN]","originCountryCode":"SG","bookingCode":"14859286949361958","destinationCountryCode":"TH","outboundInfo":{"aircraftTypes":[],"departureTime":1399956900000,"layoverInMin":0,"flightNumbers":["SQ974"],"durationInMin":205,"airportsExpanded":["SIN","BKK"],"localDepartureTimeStr":"2014/05/13 12:55 +0800","airports":["SIN","BKK"],"arrivalTime":1399969200000,"numStops":0,"flightClasses":[{"name":"Economy","fareClass":1}],"localArrivalTimeStr":"2014/05/13 15:20 +0700"}},
{"ecpcRank":0,"inboundInfo":{"aircraftTypes":[],"departureTime":1401096600000,"layoverInMin":0,"flightNumbers":["SQ977"],"durationInMin":85,"airportsExpanded":["BKK","SIN"],"localDepartureTimeStr":"2014/05/26 16:30 +0700","airports":["BKK","SIN"],"arrivalTime":1401101700000,"numStops":0,"flightClasses":[{"name":"Economy","fareClass":1}],"localArrivalTimeStr":"2014/05/26 18:55 +0800"},"location":[{"code":"BKK","name":"Bangkok"},{"code":"SIN","name":"Singapore Changi"}],"carrier":[{"name":"Singapore Airlines","code":"SQ"}],"bookingType":"WEBSITE","price":{"name":"","nameOTA":"","description":"","amount":"406","totalAmount":"406","pricePerPassenger":"406","currencyCode":"USD","totalPricePerPassenger":"406","includesTax":true},"generatedDate":1399013553833,"providerId":"singaporeair.com","id":"SQ976[SIN-BKK]|SQ977[BKK-SIN]","originCountryCode":"SG","bookingCode":"14859286965418532","destinationCountryCode":"TH","outboundInfo":{"aircraftTypes":[],"departureTime":1399968000000,"layoverInMin":0,"flightNumbers":["SQ976"],"durationInMin":205,"airportsExpanded":["SIN","BKK"],"localDepartureTimeStr":"2014/05/13 16:00 +0800","airports":["SIN","BKK"],"arrivalTime":1399980300000,"numStops":0,"flightClasses":[{"name":"Economy","fareClass":1}],"localArrivalTimeStr":"2014/05/13 18:25 +0700"}},
{"ecpcRank":0,"inboundInfo":{"aircraftTypes":[],"departureTime":1401107400000,"layoverInMin":0,"flightNumbers":["SQ979"],"durationInMin":85,"airportsExpanded":["BKK","SIN"],"localDepartureTimeStr":"2014/05/26 19:30 +0700","airports":["BKK","SIN"],"arrivalTime":1401112500000,"numStops":0,"flightClasses":[{"name":"Economy","fareClass":1}],"localArrivalTimeStr":"2014/05/26 21:55 +0800"},"location":[{"code":"BKK","name":"Bangkok"},{"code":"SIN","name":"Singapore Changi"}],"carrier":[{"name":"Singapore Airlines","code":"SQ"}],"bookingType":"WEBSITE","price":{"name":"","nameOTA":"","description":"","amount":"406","totalAmount":"406","pricePerPassenger":"406","currencyCode":"USD","totalPricePerPassenger":"406","includesTax":true},"generatedDate":1399013553835,"providerId":"singaporeair.com","id":"SQ976[SIN-BKK]|SQ979[BKK-SIN]","originCountryCode":"SG","bookingCode":"14859286967291059","destinationCountryCode":"TH","outboundInfo":{"aircraftTypes":[],"departureTime":1399968000000,"layoverInMin":0,"flightNumbers":["SQ976"],"durationInMin":205,"airportsExpanded":["SIN","BKK"],"localDepartureTimeStr":"2014/05/13 16:00 +0800","airports":["SIN","BKK"],"arrivalTime":1399980300000,"numStops":0,"flightClasses":[{"name":"Economy","fareClass":1}],"localArrivalTimeStr":"2014/05/13 18:25 +0700"}},
{"ecpcRank":0,"inboundInfo":{"aircraftTypes":[],"departureTime":1401116400000,"layoverInMin":0,"flightNumbers":["SQ981"],"durationInMin":85,"airportsExpanded":["BKK","SIN"],"localDepartureTimeStr":"2014/05/26 22:00 +0700","airports":["BKK","SIN"],"arrivalTime":1401121500000,"numStops":0,"flightClasses":[{"name":"Economy","fareClass":1}],"localArrivalTimeStr":"2014/05/27 00:25 +0800"},"location":[{"code":"BKK","name":"Bangkok"},{"code":"SIN","name":"Singapore Changi"}],"carrier":[{"name":"Singapore Airlines","code":"SQ"}],"bookingType":"WEBSITE","price":{"name":"","nameOTA":"","description":"","amount":"406","totalAmount":"406","pricePerPassenger":"406","currencyCode":"USD","totalPricePerPassenger":"406","includesTax":true},"generatedDate":1399013553839,"providerId":"singaporeair.com","id":"SQ976[SIN-BKK]|SQ981[BKK-SIN]","originCountryCode":"SG","bookingCode":"14859286971168219","destinationCountryCode":"TH","outboundInfo":{"aircraftTypes":[],"departureTime":1399968000000,"layoverInMin":0,"flightNumbers":["SQ976"],"durationInMin":205,"airportsExpanded":["SIN","BKK"],"localDepartureTimeStr":"2014/05/13 16:00 +0800","airports":["SIN","BKK"],"arrivalTime":1399980300000,"numStops":0,"flightClasses":[{"name":"Economy","fareClass":1}],"localArrivalTimeStr":"2014/05/13 18:25 +0700"}},
{"ecpcRank":0,"inboundInfo":{"aircraftTypes":[],"departureTime":1401075600000,"layoverInMin":0,"flightNumbers":["SQ973"],"durationInMin":85,"airportsExpanded":["BKK","SIN"],"localDepartureTimeStr":"2014/05/26 10:40 +0700","airports":["BKK","SIN"],"arrivalTime":1401080700000,"numStops":0,"flightClasses":[{"name":"Economy","fareClass":1}],"localArrivalTimeStr":"2014/05/26 13:05 +0800"},"location":[{"code":"BKK","name":"Bangkok"},{"code":"SIN","name":"Singapore Changi"}],"carrier":[{"name":"Singapore Airlines","code":"SQ"}],"bookingType":"WEBSITE","price":{"name":"","nameOTA":"","description":"","amount":"437","totalAmount":"437","pricePerPassenger":"437","currencyCode":"USD","totalPricePerPassenger":"437","includesTax":true},"generatedDate":1399013553842,"providerId":"singaporeair.com","id":"SQ978[SIN-BKK]|SQ973[BKK-SIN]","originCountryCode":"SG","bookingCode":"14859286974435322","destinationCountryCode":"TH","outboundInfo":{"aircraftTypes":[],"departureTime":1399977300000,"layoverInMin":0,"flightNumbers":["SQ978"],"durationInMin":205,"airportsExpanded":["SIN","BKK"],"localDepartureTimeStr":"2014/05/13 18:35 +0800","airports":["SIN","BKK"],"arrivalTime":1399989600000,"numStops":0,"flightClasses":[{"name":"Economy","fareClass":1}],"localArrivalTimeStr":"2014/05/13 21:00 +0700"}},
{"ecpcRank":0,"inboundInfo":{"aircraftTypes":[],"departureTime":1401084900000,"layoverInMin":0,"flightNumbers":["SQ975"],"durationInMin":85,"airportsExpanded":["BKK","SIN"],"localDepartureTimeStr":"2014/05/26 13:15 +0700","airports":["BKK","SIN"],"arrivalTime":1401090000000,"numStops":0,"flightClasses":[{"name":"Economy","fareClass":1}],"localArrivalTimeStr":"2014/05/26 15:40 +0800"},"location":[{"code":"BKK","name":"Bangkok"},{"code":"SIN","name":"Singapore Changi"}],"carrier":[{"name":"Singapore Airlines","code":"SQ"}],"bookingType":"WEBSITE","price":{"name":"","nameOTA":"","description":"","amount":"437","totalAmount":"437","pricePerPassenger":"437","currencyCode":"USD","totalPricePerPassenger":"437","includesTax":true},"generatedDate":1399013553848,"providerId":"singaporeair.com","id":"SQ978[SIN-BKK]|SQ975[BKK-SIN]","originCountryCode":"SG","bookingCode":"14859286980412767","destinationCountryCode":"TH","outboundInfo":{"aircraftTypes":[],"departureTime":1399977300000,"layoverInMin":0,"flightNumbers":["SQ978"],"durationInMin":205,"airportsExpanded":["SIN","BKK"],"localDepartureTimeStr":"2014/05/13 18:35 +0800","airports":["SIN","BKK"],"arrivalTime":1399989600000,"numStops":0,"flightClasses":[{"name":"Economy","fareClass":1}],"localArrivalTimeStr":"2014/05/13 21:00 +0700"}},
{"ecpcRank":0,"inboundInfo":{"aircraftTypes":[],"departureTime":1401096600000,"layoverInMin":0,"flightNumbers":["SQ977"],"durationInMin":85,"airportsExpanded":["BKK","SIN"],"localDepartureTimeStr":"2014/05/26 16:30 +0700","airports":["BKK","SIN"],"arrivalTime":1401101700000,"numStops":0,"flightClasses":[{"name":"Economy","fareClass":1}],"localArrivalTimeStr":"2014/05/26 18:55 +0800"},"location":[{"code":"BKK","name":"Bangkok"},{"code":"SIN","name":"Singapore Changi"}],"carrier":[{"name":"Singapore Airlines","code":"SQ"}],"bookingType":"WEBSITE","price":{"name":"","nameOTA":"","description":"","amount":"437","totalAmount":"437","pricePerPassenger":"437","currencyCode":"USD","totalPricePerPassenger":"437","includesTax":true},"generatedDate":1399013553854,"providerId":"singaporeair.com","id":"SQ978[SIN-BKK]|SQ977[BKK-SIN]","originCountryCode":"SG","bookingCode":"14859286986666243","destinationCountryCode":"TH","outboundInfo":{"aircraftTypes":[],"departureTime":1399977300000,"layoverInMin":0,"flightNumbers":["SQ978"],"durationInMin":205,"airportsExpanded":["SIN","BKK"],"localDepartureTimeStr":"2014/05/13 18:35 +0800","airports":["SIN","BKK"],"arrivalTime":1399989600000,"numStops":0,"flightClasses":[{"name":"Economy","fareClass":1}],"localArrivalTimeStr":"2014/05/13 21:00 +0700"}},
```

i want to print totalPricePerPassenger

following is my php code

```
$result2=curl_exec($ch);



$data = json_decode($result2);
$data = objectToArray($data);

function objectToArray($object)
{
    if (!is_object($object) && !is_array($object)) {
        return $object;
    }
    if (is_object($object)) {
        $object = (array )$object;
    }
    return array_map('objectToArray', $object);
}


foreach($data as $root){
     foreach($root as $rootOne){
        if(is_array($rootOne)){
            foreach($rootOne as $rootArrays){
                if(!empty($rootArrays["price"])){
                $priceArray = $rootArrays["price"];
                echo $priceArray["totalPricePerPassenger"];
                echo"<hr>";
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you need to make sure your JSON string is valid. Use an online linter like [JSONLint](http://jsononlint.com) for this purpose.

Note that you don't need any fancy functions like `objectToArray()` here because [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) by default allows the string to be decoded into an array (as opposed to an object). The only change you need to make is set the second parameter as `TRUE`:

```
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE); // no need to use objectToArray()
```

Then inspect the structure of the array using [`print_r()`](http://php.net/print_r):

```
echo '<pre>' . print_r($data, TRUE) . '</pre>;
```

Once you know the structure of the array, it should be pretty easy to loop through and print the required values. For printing all the `pricePerPassenger` values, simply do:

```
foreach ($data['response']['itineraries'] as $itinerary) {
    echo $itinerary['price']['pricePerPassenger'] . "\n";
}
```

[**Working demo**](https://eval.in/145364)

Comment: @TerryHiggins: Step one: enable error reporting by adding [these lines of code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6575502/1438393) to the very top of your script. Refresh the page. What error do you get?

Comment: @TerryHiggins: That means you're not getting an array. What does your JSON string look like? Where do you get it from?

Comment: @TerryHiggins: Note that I can only see an error on that page and not actual code. It would be helpful if you post the exact code somewhere so that I can see it.

Comment: Please check URL now http://lifetimecoupons.com/abs1/new.php i have added code now too

Comment: @TerryHiggins: You're missing the API key in the URL. What happens when you try to load the URL manually, in your browser? Also, it seems you did not read the answer. **Read it again.**

Answer (score 0):

Just use [json_decode($json, true);](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

You'll be returned an array which you can echo much more neatly.

Comment: false, it retuns an object

Comment: @EaterOfCode Not if you supply true as a secondary parameter.

Comment: @hindmost I know, I suggested he just uses it, rather than the unnecessary complication of the other functions.